# Node kafka consumer is receiving messages but not consumer group

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, node-kafka

I am trying to connect to my local kafka. I created a topic "test_producer" and created a producer for it using:

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --topic test_producer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

Now i am trying to connect this using node-kafka in my node application. Normal consumer is working and receiving messages but if i create a consumer group it is throwing request timeout exception

Consumer group code:

```
import { ConsumerGroup } from "kafka-node";
const options = {
    kafkaHost: "127.0.0.1:9092",
    batch: undefined,
    ssl: true,
    groupId: "ExampleGroup",
    sessionTimeout: 15000,
    protocol: ["roundrobin"],
    encoding: "utf8",
    fromOffset: "latest", // default
    commitOffsetsOnFirstJoin: true,
    outOfRangeOffset: "earliest",
    onRebalance: (isAlreadyMember, callback) => {
      callback();
    },
  };
  const consumerGroup = new ConsumerGroup(options, ["test_producer"]);
  consumerGroup.on("message", (message) => {
    console.log(`group:${message}`);
  });
```

But if i create consumer it is able to connect and receive messages.

Edit:

config/server.properties

```
############################# Server Basics #############################
broker.id=0

############################# Socket Server Settings #############################

num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600

############################# Log Basics #############################

log.dirs=/home/kafka/logs
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

############################# Internal Topic Settings  #############################
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1

############################# Log Flush Policy #############################

#log.flush.interval.messages=10000
#log.flush.interval.ms=1000

############################# Log Retention Policy #############################

log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

############################# Zookeeper #############################
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=18000


############################# Group Coordinator Settings #############################

group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
delete.topic.enable = true
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
listeners = PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
```

Comment: Can you please show your kafka server properties?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Sure. will add

Answer (score 0):

`offsets.topic.replication.factor` defaults to 3, and you won't be able to use consumer group features without the offsets topic.

Edit your broker config to set it to 1, and restart Kafka.

Also, you don't need port and advertised.host.name ; both are deprecated properties

Comment: I have updated the server.properties. It is sill not connecting.

Comment: Did the `__consumer_offsets` topic actually get created?

Comment: yes. it is listed in the topics created.

bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 -> this command lists :
__consumer_offsets, test_producer

Comment: Kafka doesn't use `ssl`, since your listeners are plaintext, so have you tried disabling that? And assuming you want to consume existing data, so setting `fromOffset` to earliest?

Comment: Yes. tried keeping ssl as false and changed fromOffset as earliest. Still its not connecting. But if i connect via consumer it is working.

Comment: Not sure, then. I suggest you use a different library that's maintained where you can get better support from the developer https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node/issues/1445

Comment: That is the package i am using too.

Comment: Yes, I know. It's not maintained. So if you're "new to Kafka" or "trying to use Nodejs with Kafka", i suggest you use an alternative library suggested in that thread since that one in particular has had no new commits in years